# HTML Table position adjustment

Tags: html, css

I have a table like this:

```
<div style="width:100px;">
<table>
    <tr>
        <td style="width:60px;"></td>
        <td style="width:60px;"></td>
        ......
    </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

When displayed on the web, the second td element will automatically move to a new line. How can I prevent such thing from happening?

Comment: Math : 60 + 60 = 120 > 100 ... What do you want ?

Comment: Edited. Number of td elements will change in case there are changes from the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if it is displayed by php, you can count td elements, then adjust width of each, for example
there is two variables: `$number_of_td`, and `$table_width`, which must be specified before.

```
<?php 
$number_of_td = 500;  //  for
$table_width = 10;    //  example
?>
<div style="width:<?php echo $table_width; ?>px;">
<table>
    <tr>

            <td style="width:<?php echo $table_width/$number_of_td; ?>px;"></td>
            <td style="width:<?php echo $table_width/$number_of_td; ?>px;"></td>

    </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

use below code

```
  <div style="width:100px;">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td style="width:50%;"></td>
            <td style="width:50%;"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Increase your div width.

```
<div style="width:100px;">
<table>
    <tr>
        <td style="width:5%;"></td>
        <td style="width:5%;"></td>
        ......
    </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

if there are `20 td` then assign accordingly to required.

Comment: Actually I am not sure about the number of td elements and there might  be 20 such td elements with width 60px.

Comment: so you can set the div width accordingly.

Comment: Do you mean that I have to use javascript to adjust the width of an div element every time the page loads?

Comment: Is you are adding/removing td dynamically ?

Comment: It will be displayed by PHP.

Comment: so you know it already. second way - you can remain the div width auto and can add as much td as you wish.

Comment: If you want those td's to be 60px and you don't know the number of td's, fixed width div won't work. Here's a width auto div fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pnR6H/2/

Comment: Nope since the width of the parent element of the div is defined, the width:auto value cannot help.

Comment: then the best way is to use the '%' in td, instead of 'px'.

Comment: Here, you can add as many td's as you want, it won't shift to the next line; http://jsfiddle.net/pnR6H/3/

Comment: Maybe I should be clear enough. Actually I want to make a horizontal which display data more efficiently.

Comment: it also depends upon your content length - if content is large then it will automatically will be shifted to next line. so one another solution is that - use the word-wrap property of td, so that words automatically adjust themselfs.

Comment: please provide the JSFiddle link, if it still not solving the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have increased the div width to "1000px" so that you can add some more columns to it, Hope this helps,

```
 <div style="width:1000px;">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td style="width:60px;"></td>
            <td style="width:60px;"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </div>
```